# Could we use strings for high precision floating-point numbers?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I am currently programming a software which needs high precision floating-point numbers. Sometimes I need more precision than a `double` can give me. I know why classic floating-point numbers can only achieve a limited amount of precision.

I was thinking about this problem and had the idea to use `string` to represent numbers and do calculation with them.

```
string number_one = "12.3459233547343432";
string number_two = "738.67632487523747384";

string sum = sum_strings(number_one, number_two);

cout << sum << endl; // 751.0222482299717...
```

The function `sum_strings` would then perform the addition like we have all learned it in primary school (just with floating-point):

[image]

Substraction would work the same way. Multiplication and division would be more complicated but it would also work.

I think theoretically you could achieve as much precision as you need (with enough RAM to store the strings).

My questions are:

1. Would this technique be much slower (for ~10 fractional digits)?
2. Is it used already and are there libraries implementing it?

Comment: This is called floating point emulation, and it is significantly slower because the native floating calculation is usually an atomic CPU commad, while emulating can take tens of CPU commands.

Comment: Assuming you mean 10 significant figures rather than 10 decimal places (otherwise, that information is not actually pertinent to the question), `double` is more than enough to precisely store the information you need. Then again, your prose doesn't match your actual examples, so who knows.

Comment: Note that `'3' + '2'` is almost certainly not equal to `'5'`, because `'3'` is not equal to `3` and `'2'` is not equal to `2` in any character encoding I've ever seen.

Comment: @Bobface: I did string-based arbitrary-precision floating-point processing, along the lines you appear to envision, in `BASIC`, ca. 1983. So it is perfectly doable, but not recommended as explained in the answers below.

Comment: I've used NTL for specialized math like Galois field operations (used in ECC). It has several high precision floating point classes and is easily incorporated in VS2015 or Linux systems.  http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/tour-struct.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would be quite a bit slower, since you'd be using a full char for a single digit of data, and operations you performed would be totally unable to use hardware-implemented arithmetic operations. A much better way would be to design an arbitrary-length binary format instead. See https://gmplib.org. There are many other options as well.

Comment: There is actually some hardware support for such character-based processing on some architectures. For example, the 32-bit `x86` architecture has instructions `AAA` (ASCII adjust after addition), `AAS` (ASCII adjust after subtraction), `AAM` (ASCII adjust after multiplication), and `AAD` (ASCII adjust after division). However, the presence of those doesn't change the fact that the efficiency of such an approach would be very poor.

Comment: Can also take advantage of the [`mpf_class`](https://gmplib.org/manual/C_002b_002b-Class-Interface.html#C_002b_002b-Class-Interface) to make things easier in C++.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but `std::string` is not the right data structure. Instead, use `std::vector<unsigned char>`, with each element of the vector holding a value in the range `0` to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max()`. That upper limit is typically 255. The rules for addition and subtraction are just like the ones you learned as a kid, except that you have 256 fingers instead of 10. That sounds flippant, but the idea is that you have a bunch of digits for a base-256 representation of a number, and the rules for adding and subtracting work the same, except that you carry when the result is greater than 255, not when it's greater than 9. That's easier than it sounds; just do the arithmetic with a larger unsigned type; the result % 256 is the value in the current digit, and the result / 256 is the amount to carry.

Once you've wrapped your thoughts around that, you could also consider using `std::vector<unsigned long long>` instead of `std::vector<unsigned char>`, which would mean doing arithmetic in base-2^64.